# jquery repetitive else if

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I don't like the way I'm programming and I want to improve the following script by eiminating the repetitive else if, or by making it shorter. Any suggestions?

```
var trouv;
if($("#ch5").is(":not(:empty)")) trouv = $("#ch5").text();
else if($("#ch4").is(":not(:empty)")) trouv = $("#ch4").text();
else if($("#ch3").is(":not(:empty)")) trouv = $("#ch3").text();
else if($("#ch2").is(":not(:empty)")) trouv = $("#ch2").text();
else if($("#ch1").is(":not(:empty)")) trouv = $("#ch1").text();
else trouv=0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all your ids start with `ch`, you can use the attribute [**starts with**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```
var trouv = $('[id^="ch"]:not(:empty)').text() || 0;
```

The **OR** `0` at the end effectively replaces the last `else`

Comment: In case of (ch1, ch2, ch3) not empty and (ch4, ch5) empty, trouv would be assigned three values!

Comment: I want to get the last non-empty value.

Comment: Try adding `:last` like `$('[id^="ch"]:not(:empty):last')`